# Как использовать расширенную версию ASCII table - (The extended ASCII codes (character code 128-255)) в языке Си

Tags: c, ascii

Компьютер MacBook Air 13. Система OSX ElCapitan. 
Компилирую код через терминал

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>


int main(void) {
    unsigned char c;
    for (c = 32; c <= 255; c++) {
        printf("%c",c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

На выходе получаю

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????????`.
```

то есть выводятся символы до 127 кода из таблицы. А дальше заменяется все вопросами. Как использовать расширенную ASCII таблицу в диапазоне 128-255. Таблицу использовал по ссылке http://www.ascii-code.com/. Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Comment: Ты не представляешь, в какие сложности ты пытаешься окунуться, но если коротко, то надо забыть про то, что символ = 1 байт, и вперёд на Unicode!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте переключиться на стандартную локаль. В тело функции `main()` добавьте  `setlocale (LC_ALL,"");` или `setlocale (LC_ALL,"C");`

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло. Ничего не поменялось. Пробывал тот же самый код на компьютере под Windows, там таких проблем нету.